# 2 apache instances on the same network?

Tags: php, linux, windows, apache, multiple-instances

Okay, I've tried searching for this question but either I don't understand or I'm searching the wrong thing. It may be simple, or not even possible.

I'm under a router with 1 static IP address (ISP doesn't allow 2 IP's without a business account)

I have 3 domains names set up with Apache vHosts at port 80,  all these are on my Windows side @ my local ip 192.168.1.2:80 - example1(2)(3).com

I have a Linux server that I'm VM'ing with a game server and a Apache server, the only reason I need apache on my linux side is because a script that calls PHP socket requests only works on this side @ 192.168.1.4:421

Heres the question: My example3.com domain is on my Windows side and it has a few directories that need to stay on the windows, I can reach my other server at example3.com:421/example, I want traffic to be able to goto example3.com/example and reach example3.com:421/example without showing the port location though in the Windows vHosts, I'm not able to set a DocumentRoot because it's actually on the Linux side how would I set something like that up? I've looked into mod_proxy but I'm not 100% if it would work & I don't need a whole lot of downtime on my first 2 domains. Please help! Someone said to do port translation on it but I have a Netgear N600 & can't find anything about port translation.

**Thanks so much in advance!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not able to set a DocumentRoot because it's actually on the Linux
>   side

You could export directories on the Linux machine via SAMBA, map them on the Windows machine, and then configure Apache to access these directories.

Another option is to configure URL redirection on the Windows machine. You could redirect the URLs like example3.com/example to example3.com:421/example. You would need to configure port forwarding on your router to forward port 421 to port 80 of the Linux box

[See here](http://www.ports3658.com/2012/05/netgear-n600-port-forwarding.html), but I am sure there are many references available.

Comment: I'd love to get SAMBA installed on this thing, but it's RHEL4 and I don't have a key for it. My game server requires RHEL4 only, so I'm kind of in a pickle I guess & I can't port forward 421 to 80 because it says it's already used (My Windows Apache is on 80 which is opened already, 192.168.1.2) Thanks for the help though!

Comment: I am not sure why the Windows port 80 is conflicting with Linux port 80. When you forward 421, you have to specify the target port and IP address (Linux machine). That should work. And even so, it doesn't have to be 80. You can run the Apache server on any port, and then forward 421 to that port.

Comment: Yeah me either, do you know much about a reverse proxy? I don't seem to understand it but I think that may be the route I have to go.